# Is releasing a property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have a property which is declared as:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) DateClass *dateClass;
```

I have this piece of code where I need to copy a new instance into it:

```
//Do I need to release dateClass here first before assigning new instance?
self.dateClass = [self getOtherDateClass];

...
-(DateClass*) getOtherDateClass
{
  DateClass *dateClass = [[[DateClass alloc]init]autoRelease];

  return dateClass;         
}
```

Do I need to release `self.dateClass` before setting it to a new instance which is autoreleased or is the synthesized property already doing this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A @property that's declared using `retain` or `copy` will release the old object for you, assuming you're using the synthesized setter for that property.

Comment: Ok but is it wise to autorelease the new object before assigning? Is there a possibility the autorelease kicking in too soon, making my class object invalid?

Comment: Autorelease won't kick in until the current iteration of the runloop has ended, so you don't have to worry about it kicking in "early" unless you do some stuff on your own with autorelease pools.